# Replacing pom dependency through shell script

Tags: shell, sed, sh, xmlstarlet

I am reading pom.xml and uplifting dependency through shell script

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>gin</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

where I want to uplift guice version to 3.0, Is there any way where I can replace particular artifactId dependencies through shell script.

So output should be as below

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
          <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
          <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.gwt.inject</groupId>
          <artifactId>gin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it. Try to show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see someone else tagged your question with xmlstarlet. If xmlstarlet is an option I don't think there would be any good reason to choose sed or awk.

The only thing that might trip you up is POMs usually have a default namespace so you need to make sure to account for it.

Here's an example...

**POM XML Input**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.gwt.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>gin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </dependency>            
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

**xmlstarlet command line**

```
xml ed -L -N p="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" -u "//p:dependency[p:artifactId='guice']/p:version" -v "3.0" pom.xml
```

**POM XML Output**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>gin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

**Caution:** The `-L` will edit the file inplace. [See here for more details.](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139594320)

**----- Update -----**

To add `-SNAPSHOT` to the version number, use `-x` (expression) instead of `-v`...

```
xml ed -L -N p="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" -u "//p:dependency[p:artifactId='guice']/p:version" -x "concat(normalize-space(),'-SNAPSHOT')" pom.xml
```

**Output**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>gin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: Is there any way where we can find out the version? of any artifact and replaces version with version-SNAPSHOT? in shell script

Comment: @Ganesh - so instead of changing the version of guice to “3.0” it should be “2.0-SNAPSHOT”?

Comment: Yes!, It has dynamically identify  the version and replace with -SNAPSHOT

Comment: @Ganesh - That you can do that by using `-x` to output an xpath expression instead of a static value. Please see my update.

Comment: Hally I modified command to xml ed -L -N p="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" -u "//*[p:artifactId='${repo_name}']/p:version" -x "concat(normalize-space(),'-SNAPSHOT')" pom.xml, Because my repo name was outside dependency, And My whole file got changed, Can you please 
check  the command

Comment: @Ganesh - I'm not sure what you mean by "My whole file got changed"; the only elements that should update are those matched by the xpath in `-u`. Feel free to update your question with a different example that includes using the `repo_name` variable (or ask a new question). I tried it locally with `repo_name="guice"` and it still works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way (imho) would be to use [Properties](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties) to define versions of the dependencies in your POM. For example like this:

```
<properties>
   <guice.version>2.0</guice.version>
   <gin.version>2.0</gin.version>
</properties>
...
<dependencies>
...
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
      <version>${guice.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>gin</artifactId>
      <version>${gin.version}</version>
   </dependency>
```

This makes replacing the version of a specific dependency later on easier. In the future, each time you'd need to do it, you could do a simple `sed`:

```
sed -i 's|<guice.version>.*</guice.version>|<guice.version>3.0</guice.version>|g' pom.xml
```

Comment: @Zdnek Is there any way where we can find out the version? of any artifact and replaces version with version-SNAPSHOT? in shell script

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with `sed`:

```
sed -r '/<artifactId>guice<\/artifactId>/ { N; s/(<version>).*?(<\/version>)/\13.0\2/ }' pom.xml > pom_new.xml
```

Here's a solution with `awk`:

```
awk 'last ~ "<artifactId>guice</artifactId>" && $0 ~ "version" { gsub("<version>.*?</version>","<version>3.0</version>") } { last = $0 } 1;' pom.xml > pom_new.xml
```

Both commands will create new file `pom_new.xml` with your desired output.

Comment: Is there any way where we can find out the version? of any artifact and replaces version with version-SNAPSHOT? in shell script